# How do I add a prefix to Format-List output?

Tags: powershell, lync, lync-2013

I need to generate an import file in the format of `sip:username@domain.com` for the [Lync User Management](https://lumt.codeplex.com/) tool.

I'm using this PowerShell commmand:

```
Get-DistributionGroupmember FirmOperationS@company.com  | Select-Object primarysmtpaddress
```

I'm having trouble prepending the characters "sip:" to the column output, and saving it to a CSV using `Export-Csv`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a custom/calculated property:

```
Get-DistributionGroupmember FirmOperationS@company.com  |
Select-Object @{n="PrimarySMTPAddress";e={ "sip:$($_.primarysmtpaddress)" }}
```

If you only need that property, you could also replace Select-Object with Foreach-Object, like

```
Get-DistributionGroupmember FirmOperationS@company.com  |
ForEach-Object { "sip:$($_.primarysmtpaddress)" }
```

Comment: awesome, works like a charm,, and now I learned 2 ways of doing it!